# Can we train EigenVectors model with BigInt labels in OpenCv C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to build a soft for *face recognition using OpenCv with C++* implementation. The problem i am having is that i have a lot of faces, more than 10 million, which can not be labeled just using INT type(vector /int/ labels). I tried using long long int, but i get this error after some time of training(after 0.5 seconds):

**OpenCV Error**: Bad argument (Labels must be given as integer (CV_32SC1). Expected 4, but was 7.) in train, file /home/roka/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp, line 349 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  /home/roka/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp:349: error: (-5) Labels must be given as integer (CV_32SC1). Expected 4, but was 7. in function train

Answer (score 0):

if you're going for *millions* of faces, you 've got more problems, than ints being too small to label them.

the eigenface approach will need *far* more memory than can fit into a single machine, as you need to give it *all* available data in one go for the training.

you'll have to break that data into several chunks, and choose an algo ( i.e, lbp ) that can live with *independant* measurements combined. also you'll need a separate index, that translates int-labels (from a local recognition) into global bigint labels again

Comment: I was able to change the code a bit(uncommented some lines) in opencv's code so that it accepts BigInt labels. But not sure whether it is acceptable and that i will not get into trouble in the future.